# dotnet build Access to the path '/.dotnet' is denied for Linux, my user is nobody

Tags: c#, docker

dotnet build Access to the path '/.dotnet' is denied for Linux Docker. My user is 'nobody', and the 'root' user is able to run successfully. I want the 'nobody' user to be able to use the 'dotnet build or run' command successfully too, what should I do?
My dotnet info is:

```
/home/demo # dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.402
 Commit:    e9d3381880

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     alpine
 OS Version:  3.13
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         alpine.3.13-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.402/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.11
  Commit:  f431858f8b

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.11 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.11 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

[nobody](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nATMW.png)

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/csharp $ docker run -it --user nobody csharp /bin/sh
~ $ cd home/demo/
/home/demo $ dotnet build
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/.dotnet' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.IO.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(String fullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.EnvironmentAbstractions.DirectoryWrapper.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FileSystemExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CreateIfNotExists>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.FileAccessRetrier.RetryOnIOException(Action action)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FileSystemExtensions.CreateIfNotExists(IFileSystem fileSystem, String filePath)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.FileSentinel.Create()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Configurer.DotnetFirstTimeUseConfigurer.Configure()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ConfigureDotNetForFirstTimeUse(IFirstTimeUseNoticeSentinel firstTimeUseNoticeSentinel, IAspNetCertificateSentinel aspNetCertificateSentinel, IFileSentinel toolPathSentinel, Boolean isDotnetBeingInvokedFromNativeInstaller, DotnetFirstRunConfiguration dotnetFirstRunConfiguration, IEnvironmentProvider environmentProvider, Dictionary`2
performanceMeasurements)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

[root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMSt5.png)

```
/home/demo # dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.1+3e40a09f8 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  demo -> /home/demo/bin/Debug/net5.0/demo.dll

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.34
/home/demo # whoami
root
```

Comment: What's the permissions for the `/home/demo` folder? And does the `.dotnet` folder exist when running with the nobody user?

Comment: `/home/demo` folder permissions have been set to '777', `/.dotnet` is not present

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly specify the `DOTNET_CLI_HOME` environment variable to a writable directory, like `/tmp`:

```bash
docker run -it --user nobody -e DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/tmp csharp /bin/sh
```

See also: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/pull/9327 and https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/main/src/Common/CliFolderPathCalculatorCore.cs#L14